# org.json.JSONException: No value for employeeLst

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse a JSON Array and I get the No value for employeeLst Error.I have tried 
all combination.

**JSON**

```
{"response": {
   "status": "success",
   "data": {"employeeLst":    [
            {
         "employeeID": 1,
         "name": "Diwakar",
         "year": "2015",
         "employeeDate": "Nov 21, 2015"
      },
            {
         "employeeID": 2,
         "name": "Ponni",
         "year": "2015",
         "employeeDate": "Nov 21, 2015"
      },
            {
         "employeeID": 3,
         "name": "Mahashi",
         "year": "2015",
         "employeeDate": "Nov 21, 2015"
      },
            {
         "employeeID": 4,
         "name": "Ganesh",
         "year": "2015",
         "employeeDate": "Nov 21, 2015"
      },
            {
         "employeeID": 5,
         "name": "Namarata",
         "year": "2015",
         "employeeDate": "Nov 21, 2015"
      }
   ]}
}}

Code
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
employees = jsonObj.getJSONArray("emplyeeLst");
```

Throws a error in the above line saying No value for employeeLst.Please share the code in Android.

Comment: `employeeLst` JSONAray is in `data` JSONObject. so you will need to get first `data`  JSONObject and then `employeeLst` JSONArray from `data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

`employees = jsonObj.getJSONObject("response").getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("employeeLst");`